# Is it possible to increase the transaction fee of a sent transaction not yet in a block?

Tags: transaction-fees, transaction-selection

Is it possible to increase transaction fee of a transaction that is already  sent and seems stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Today? No.

There was a feature that was developed referred to as [child pays for parent](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/1647) however few miners if any are using this patch.

There have been instances where mining pool operators have been offered a bounty to include a specific transactions, but there is no automated process for that and presumably would require a significant incentive.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't "edit" in a transaction, but you can doublespend the transaction (e.g. create a new transaction with a higher fee, but reuse the same output as the other transaction).

I'm not sure it's possible in Bitcoin-QT (without doing some ninja tricks), but you might be able to do it by using Armory to create a offline transaction (e.g. Armory don't know about the sent transaction if it only get the wallet and blockchain on a offline computer).

Comment: Won't such double spending have negative consequences? Did anybody tried it?

Comment: This wont be a double spend, because it is impossible to double spend ;) Blockchain.info (or someone else) might log double spend attempts, but I can't really think of any 'punishment' by doing so :)

Comment: Nodes that already know about the first transaction will not relay your double spend attempt, and the possibility of success depends on quirks such as a miner not knowing of the original transaction due to a restart and then takes the double spend attempt as it seemed to be legit.  Suggesting a double spend as a workaround is not good advice.